# rolling computation based on values

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I need to integrate the area under a curve, but I want to do it in intervals of 5m rather than computing the entire area at once. I.e, I want to compute the area between x = 0-5m, 5-10m,10-15m, 15-20m, etc. However, the spacing between my x values is irregular, so I need the window of my rolling computation to be based on values rather than on index. I have based some of my code on the answer to a similar question, but I am still getting errors.

I would like the output to be an array with a column for the x interval and a column for the area.

Here is some example data (the actual data frame goes from x = 0 --> 37, with 67 rows):

```
       X     Y
0    0.0   0.0
1    1.0  -0.5
2    1.5  -1.0
3    2.0  -2.0 
4    3.0  -3.0
5    4.0  -4.0
6    5.5  -4.5
7    6.0  -5.0
8    6.7  -6.0
9    8.0  -6.5
10   9.0  -7.0
11  10.0  -8.0
12  11.5  -9.0
13  12.0 -10.0
14  12.5 -10.5
15  13.0 -11.0
16  15.0 -11.5
```

Here is an example function of what this might look like for just one 5 m interval.

```
from scipy.integrate import simps 

def partial_area (y, x):
    x =df.query(' 0 <= X <= 5')['X']
    y =df.query('0 <= X <= 5)['Z']
    area = simps(y,x)
    return (area)

area = partial_area(y,x)
```

I need to do this over the entire data frame. Below is the code I've written for this. However, I keep getting an "IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0" error. I realize I must be producing an empty array at some point in the function, but I'm having trouble interpreting the error message to understand exactly where the error is or how to fix it.

```
def partial_area(x):
    x_int =df.X[(df.X >= 5*x) & (df.X < (5*x)+5)] #x array
    y_int = df.Z[(df.X >= 5*x) & (df.X < (5*x)+5)] #y array 
    area = simps (y_int, x_int) # simpson's rule function 
    return (area)

max_x = int(max(df.X))  
for x in range(0,max_x+5, 5):
    area = partial_area(x)



IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-3e4e55b7b52d> in <module>
     18 max_x = int(max(df.X))
     19 for x in range(0,max_x+5, 5):
---> 20     area = partial_area(x)
     21 

<ipython-input-49-3e4e55b7b52d> in partial_area(x)
     13     x_int =df.X[(df.X >= 5*x) & (df.X < (5*x)+5)] #x array
     14     y_int = df.Z[(df.X >= 5*x) & (df.X < (5*x)+5)] #y array
---> 15     area = simps (y_int, x_int) #simpson's rule function
     16     return (area)
     17 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py in simps(y, x, dx, axis, even)
    485             slice2 = tupleset(slice2, axis, -2)
    486             if x is not None:
--> 487                 last_dx = x[slice1] - x[slice2]
    488             val += 0.5*last_dx*(y[slice1]+y[slice2])
    489             result = _basic_simps(y, 0, N-3, x, dx, axis)

IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: `0-5m, 5-10m,10-15m, 15-20m` is not rolling, rather bucketing. `0-5, 1-6, 1-7...` is rolling.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good insight. But by bucketing, do you mean binning the data?

Comment: Yes, binning. And you should be looking at `pd.cut`, then groupby.

Comment: Thanks for the help! pd.cut and groupby worked for me. If you want to write up a response to the question, I'll give you the answer.